# Making POP3 email account

Tags: linux, pop3

My company's website and email are on a third-party Linux server offered with no sysadmin support.  I need to add some email addresses to the thing, and I've been specifically asked for POP3 accounts.

Despite its name, the `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/addpop` script adds IMAP email accounts.  The CPanel interface doesn't offer any sort of functionality for adding email accounts. [**Edit:** this instantiation of the CPanel interface doesn't offer any functionality for adding email accounts.  I'm led to believe CPanel interfaces offered by host providers that don't hate their customers can typically do this just fine.]

Anybody have any advice for making POP3 accounts?  And is there an easy way to convert an existing IMAP account into POP3 without going through the hassle of "make sure all the messages are downloaded to client/delete the IMAP account/create a POP3 account with the same name"?

Comment: Which version of cPanel? With version 11, you add mail accounts at `http://<cpanel>/frontend/x3/mail/pops.html`

Comment: Are there already existing email accounts and are they configured on this webserver?

Comment: @iglvzx:  It's WHM 11.30.6 (build 3).  That URL isn't recognized.

Comment: @music2myear:  There are existing accounts configured here, but as far as I can tell, they're all IMAP.

Comment: @lik:  "What? No. It can't be as simple as having my client treat the account as POP3 instead of IMAP, can it? Surely I already tried treating it as POP3 and failed!" *experiment* *experiment* "Oh god dammit...." Thank you for the education, mate. I now feel very silly for having created a problem where none actually existed. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, there's a shiny checkmark in it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POP and IMAP are just protocols which are used to retrieve email messages from the server. Regardless of protocol in use from the client side MDA is the same (assume Dovecot if we are talking about recent cPanel versions). So, you should either re-configure Dovecot not to support IMAP on the server [1] or just block access to IMAP/IMAPs protocol ports with the help of firewall.

[1]
`WHM -> Service Configuration -> Mailserver Configuration -> Protocols Enabled`

Comment: You can delete your comment. :)